# spring-web maven dependency not being published with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, google-app-engine, maven, spring-mvc

My **gae + spring + maven** project works perfectly. But I can't make it work using **eclipse**.

Seems like the **spring-web** dependency declared in my *pom.xml* **is disappearing** from *WEB-INF/lib* when I run my project using GAE from eclipse (using Google Plugin, *Run As > Web Application*). So without **spring-web** this is the exception:

```
Could not instantiate listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

(Full GAE stacktrace [here](http://pastebin.com/RyupC7ru))

From console, running `mvn clean package gae:run`, the app works like a charm and **spring-web** is placed under *WEB-INF/lib directory* as expected.

Just published my test project at BitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/jelies/gae-spring-maven

*Any idea why **spring-web** is not being published to **WEB-INF/lib** when launching webapp from eclipse?*

---

Using:

- SpringSource ToolSuite 3.1.0 (based on eclipse 3.8)
- Java 6
- Spring 3.2.1
- Maven 3.0.4
- Google App Engine 1.7.5
- maven-gae-plugin 0.9.6

---

**Update:** *spring-web* dependency is being published to *WEB-INF/lib* when using spring version **3.1.4.RELEASE**. This is not happening with any 3.2.X version.

Comment: Do you run the dev-server with the m2eclipse plugin and the same goals as on the console? Or you want to start the dev server with the google plugin (run as-> web application)?

Comment: I want to start the dev server with the google plugin, using "run as -> web application" as you said.

Comment: You should use the [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse/) plugin and start the dev server with maven. Maven copies every (server) dependency to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. The `pom.xml` doesn't affect the google plugin (in any case). If you want to run the server with the google plugin you'll have to copy the whole libraries on your own to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. The same procedure is needed if you want to deploy your project with the google plugin to the GAE. So in my opinion it is better (and much easier) to use maven in both cases. Or do you really need the google plugin?

Comment: If I compile with maven or copy manually all the dependecies to *WEB-INF/lib*, when I run my app with google plugin, *spring-web* dependency is deleted and dev server starts with the error above :( Things are easier with the google plugin I think (debug/stop server), and all works as expected, but this dependency is being deleted! I will try using maven inside eclipse, thanks for your tips :)

Comment: ahg, come on! I can't understand this! Using spring 3.1.4.RELEASE version, works perfect from console and from eclipse using google plugin... WTF? spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE is not being published and spring-web-3.1.x.RELEASE does...

Comment: Wow, that's suspicious :/ . Never had such a magic problem with the dev server. Can you try to run your application on a tomcat or jetty? Does this server also delete the libs? Are the 3.2.1 libs signed jars? Because GAE doesn't support signed jars -> [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3754), nah but normaly the this doesn't affect the dev server (only the GAE). Maybe some spring gurus can answer the question.

Comment: Tried with tomcat and works OK, spring-web is published as other dependencies :( I will use spring 3.1.4 for the moment. Maybe this weird thing gets fixed in future versions of spring/gae/eclipse/gpe. Thanks @da_re for your help :)

Comment: @jelies Have you experienced this issue with the m2e plugin for Eclipse, without the plugin, or in both cases? I'm experiencing the same thing in Eclipse Juno Service Release 2, although I do NOT have m2e installed. Using Eclipse 4.2 and WAS 7.0

Comment: I tried only with m2e plugin, not without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, spring 3.2.x with eclipse and maven is not working; `spring-web` is not being published to *WEB-INF/lib* when launching the application from Google Eclipse Plugin.

Tried with Spring 3.2.1 and 3.2.2. It's only working for me using lower versions (now I'm using 3.1.4).

Answer (score 2):

Added a Jira issue for this problem with my configuration (Eclipse 4.2, WAS 7.0, mvn 3): https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10494

Comment: In my case this is happening with Google App Engine instead WAS7, but maybe there is a bug related to that. Thanks for the JIRA, I will follow any update there.

Answer (score 1):

If your .classpath file has the entry `<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>`, try changing it to your WEB-INF/classes dir. Mine is set up with maven standards, so I changed this line to `<classpathentry kind="output" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes"/>`. This just fixed my issues (Eclipse Juno, WAS 7, no m2e install).

Also, in case it applies to others, I should mention that with my server (Websphere) I am choosing the "Run server with resources within the workspace" publishing setting.

This issue shows how much I really don't understand Eclipse's publishing still, but before that change when I chose the "in workspace" setting it actually published my resources to \workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0 and the WEB-INF\lib did not contain spring-web. However, with the change above I'm no longer seeing my code published to that directory. I'm not exactly sure now how my server is getting the binaries it needs, but it appears to be working.

As a side note/added bonus (maybe completely unrelated), I no longer need to do a publish to see updates to my JSPs when I make changes to them.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

1. Find the location of the spring-web.jar this is being included in you web app. In my case its in user.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.1.6.RELEASE\spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
2. Open spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar en eg. 7zip
3. Delete this file from the jar: META-INF\web-fragment.xml (in 7zip right click the file -> delete)
4. Close 7zip and run "Publish" on the server in Eclipse

More info: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10494?focusedCommentId=94572&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-94572